# How to write regex to handle multiple spaces?

Tags: regex

I need a regex that will get the name of a label. The labels look like this:

```
lbl LabelName
```

The regex will need to return LabelName. I manged to make this:

```
(?<=\slbl\s).+?(?=\s)
```

This works fine as long there is only one character between "lbl" and "LabelName". If I add two spaces or more spaces then it will return the extra spaces.

I tried `(?<=\slbl\s+).+?(?=\s)` but it doesn't work either.

Comment: I solved it using a without using a regex. I used a lexer that I created a while back.

Comment: Your comment could be added as an answer.  Can you post it?  (And the code for the lexer if it's short enough and you own it?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does the following regular expression work for you?

```
lbl\s+([^\s]+)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this: `^lbl\s+(\S+)$`. In 1st group you obtain `LabelName`.

Answer (score 0):

You can keep the extra spaces with the 'lbl' part and still capture `LabelName` with something like this:

```
^lbl\s+(.*)
```